# Masking a Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

Lets suppose i have two sequences $data$ and $mask$, where $mask$ consists of as many zeroes and/or ones as $data$ has elements.

Now apply the $mask$ to the $data$ - the result is a new sequence with all the entries $data_i$ for which $mask_i=1$ (preserving order).

Example:

$$
\begin{align}
data & =(4,8,3,2,5,7,1,0) \\\\
mask & =(0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1) \\\\
\\\\
maskSequence(data, mask) & =(8,3,5,0) \\\\
maskSequence(data, \lnot mask) & =(4,2,7,1)
\end{align}
$$

How could i express *maskSequence(data, mask)* mathematically?